# how to get all data from tables using join even if there is no match

Tags: mysql, laravel, join, eloquent

i want to have all the records from district table even if there is no match in cases table in following query

```
$object = DB::table('case_details as cd')
    ->select(
        DB::RAW('SUM(cd.registered) AS registered'),
        "prv.$name AS province",
        "crt.$name AS court",
        "dis.$name AS divan",
        "c.court_id",
        "c.divan_id"
    );
    ->leftJoin('cases AS c','c.id','cd.case_id')
    ->leftJoin('provinces as prv','prv.id','=','c.province_id')
    ->leftJoin('courts as crt','crt.id','=','c.court_id');
    ->rightJoin('districts as dis','dis.id','=','c.district_id');
        
$object = $object->groupBy("dis.id");
$object = $object->orderBy("c.province_id", 'ASC');

if($object->count() > 0)
    return $object->get();
        
return false;
```

now i am getting only the districts which has match in cases table

Comment: do you try left join?

Comment: @alirezadp10 id does not make any different using left or right, i thinks it is because the districts table does not join directly to main table(case_details) so it brings the data according to cases id in case_details